# What is the best way to sort results from the Nearby Search in Google API by Rating?

Tags: javascript, react-native, sorting, google-maps, google-places-api

I'm using Javascript(React-Native) right now, and I'm trying to get some nearby places using Nearby Search in Google API.

What should I do if I want to sort the results based on Rating?

+I want to sort only places that are more than the specified Rating.

Comment: What is the query you are using and what is the related data structure?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use Javascripts inbuild Array `sort()` function with a custom `compare function`.

https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort

a compare function for you could look like this:

```
function cCompare (a,b){
 if(a.rating < b.rating){
   return 1; 
 }
 if(arating > b.rating){
   return -1;
 }
   return 0; 
}
```